# How to add sound when back button is pressed in complete application

Tags: android, back-button

My application is very big and has many activities and fragments, is there any easy option to add sound when back button is pressed anytime anywhere in app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `onBackPressed()` method of your activity class

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();

    String tonePath = "android.resource://in.plackal.juswrite2/raw/" + R.raw.tone1;
    RingtoneManager ringToneManager = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(tonePath));

    ringToneManager.play();

    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom class `BaseActivity` which extends `Activity` class.

In that, override `onBackPressed` like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        //play sound

    }
}
```

Now, in all your activities, extend `BaseActivity` instead of `Activity`.

```
public class MyActivity1 extends BaseActivity{

}
```

and

```
public class MyActivity2 extends BaseActivity{

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to `@Override` the `onBackPressed()`, and then inside of this method put the sound.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d("back", "onBackPressed Called");
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.AudioFile);
    mp.start();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Derive all your activities from a base activity and play your sound in onBackPressed in the base activity.

O.K. I voted for one of the faster answers (FlamePrincess) that included code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) class to play small sound files.

Override Back button for every Activity and play the sound inside that method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   // Write your sound play logic over here
}
```